# showing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (y_n-y_{n+1})$ converges $\Leftrightarrow$ $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to show for $x_n:=y_n-y_{n+1}\in\mathbb C$:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges $\Leftrightarrow$ $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge

I've tried the following:

$(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converge $\Leftrightarrow$ $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy-sequence $\Leftrightarrow $ for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for alle $n\geq m\geq n_0$: $|y_m-y_{n+1}|<\epsilon$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall\epsilon>0\exists n_0\in\mathbb N:\forall m\geq n\geq n_0:\left|\sum_{k=m}^nx_k\right|<\epsilon$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ converges by Cauchy

Can you do it this way? And are there any easier ways if my one is incorrect?

Comment: There is no need for an Cauchy sequence argument. Just calculate partial sum of $x_n$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n-y_{n+1}$ is convergent if and only if the partial sum $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} y_k-y_{k+1}=y_1-y_n$ is convergent which means that $(y_n)_n$ is convergent.

Comment: thanks, what about my attempt?

Comment: As said in Du Phan's comment there's no need for an Cauchy sequence argument.

Comment: Wow, you've had a busy day or two! +1

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-y_{i+1})=\sum_{i=1}^ny_i-\sum_{j=2}^{n+1}S_j=y_1-y_{n+1}.
$$
If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(y_n-y_{n+1})$ converges, i.e.
$$
S:=\lim_nS_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(y_n-y_{n+1})<\infty,
$$
then we have
$$
\lim_ny_n=\lim_n(y_1-S_{n-1})=y_1-S.
$$
Conversely, if $(y_n)$ converges, say with $y_\infty=\lim_ny_n$, then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(y_n-y_{n+1})=\lim_nS_n=y_1-y_\infty.
$$

Comment: Do not use $\sum_n(y_n-y_{n-1})<\infty$ as synonym for "exists". This is only correct if the terms of the series are positive. Here, they are complex numbers.